# Getting previous window data in DataFlow

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow, sliding-window

Trying to create some mechanism of alerting system, I am looking to find a drop in an average between two windows.

I was happy to find [TrafficRoutes](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowSDK-examples/blob/master-1.x/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/examples/complete/TrafficRoutes.java) example, specifically when I saw it says:

> A 'slowdown' occurs if a supermajority of speeds in a sliding window
>   are less than the **reading of the previous window**.

I looked in the [code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowSDK-examples/blob/master-1.x/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/examples/complete/TrafficRoutes.java#L230), but failed to understand why this means we get the previous value from the previous window. Since I had no experience with sliding windows till now, I thought I might missing something.

Implementing this kind of mechanism, with or without sliding windows - does not get data from previous windows, as I suspected.

Any idea what do I miss ?
Is there a certain way to get values from previous window ?

I am executing on GCP Dataflow, with SDK 1.9.0.

Please advise,

Shushu

Comment: Hmm, the quote in your post does not match the text in the code - it says "If a supermajority of speeds in this sliding window are less than the previous reading we call this a 'slowdown'", there is no mention of "previous window". The code looks at the previous speed measurement for a particular station, by processing the full list of all speed measurements of all stations on a given route, sorted by timestamp.

Comment: In general the concept of "previous window" is not well-defined: e.g. if a key has 3 windows [1, 3], [2, 3] and [1, 2], which one is the "previous" for [2,3]? Moreover, all windows are processed at the same time and not necessarily in any particular order. You can think of a window as simply another implicit grouping key for aggregation/grouping operations such as GroupByKey and Combine.

Comment: I think there's still a reasonable way to accomplish your original goal, even if TrafficRoutes is not the best example to mimic. Let me write that up in an answer...

Comment: Thanks. The quote comes from https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/examples/all-examples#traffic-routes

Answer (score 2):

My assumptions:

- Your alerting system has data partitioned into "metrics" identified by "metric ids".
- The value of a metric at a given time is `Double`.
- You are receiving the metric data as a `PCollection<KV<String, Double>>` where the `String` is metric id, the `Double` is the metric value, and each element has the appropriate implicit timestamp (if it doesn't, you can assign one using the `WithTimestamps` transform).
- You want to compute sliding averages of each metric for each 5-minute interval starting at every 1 minute, and want to do something in case the average for interval starting at T+1min is smaller than average for interval starting at T

You can accomplish it like this:

```
PCollection<KV<String, Double>> metricValues = ...;
// Collection of (metric, timestamped 5-minute average)
// windowed into the same 5-minute windows as the input,
// where timestamp is assigned as the beginning of the window.
PCollection<KV<String, TimestampedValue<Double>>>
  metricSlidingAverages = metricValues
    .apply(Window.<KV<String, Double>>into(
        SlidingWindows.of(Duration.standardMinutes(5))
                      .every(Duration.standardMinutes(1))))
    .apply(Mean.<String, Double>perKey())
    .apply(ParDo.of(new ReifyWindowFn()));

// Rewindow the previous collection into global window so we can
// do cross-window comparisons.
// For each metric, an unsorted list of (timestamp, average) pairs.
PCollection<KV<String, Iterable<TimestampedValue<Double>>>
  metricAverageSequences = metricSlidingAverages
    .apply(Window.<KV<String, TimestampedValue<Double>>>into(
        new GlobalWindows()))
    // We need to group the data by key again since the grouping key
    // has changed (remember, GBK implicitly groups by key and window)
    .apply(GroupByKey.<String, TimestampedValue<Double>>create())

metricAverageSequences.apply(new DetectAnomaliesFn());

...

class ReifyWindowFn extends DoFn<
    KV<String, Double>, KV<String, TimestampedValue<Double>>> {
  @ProcessElement
  public void process(ProcessContext c, BoundedWindow w) {
    // This DoFn makes the implicit window of the element be explicit
    // and extracts the starting timestamp of the window.
    c.output(KV.of(
      c.element().getKey(),
      TimestampedValue.of(c.element.getValue(), w.minTimestamp())));
  }
}

class DetectAnomaliesFn extends DoFn<
    KV<String, Iterable<TimestampedValue<Double>>>, Void> {
  @ProcessElement
  public void process(ProcessContext c) {
    String metricId = c.element().getKey();
    // Sort the (timestamp, average) pairs by timestamp.
    List<TimestampedValue<Double>> averages = Ordering.natural()
        .onResultOf(TimestampedValue::getTimestamp)
        .sortedCopy(c.element().getValue());
    // Scan for anomalies.
    for (int i = 1; i < averages.size(); ++i) {
      if (averages.get(i).getValue() < averages.get(i-1).getValue()) {
        // Detected anomaly! Could do something with it,
        // e.g. publish to a third-party system or emit into
        // a PCollection.
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that I did not test this code, but it should provide enough conceptual guidance for you to accomplish the task.

Comment: First, thanks a lot !
Second, won't this kind of solution, considering running on streaming data, will blow up very fast ? We push into the global window all of the data, don't we ? Anyway I will play with it, and see how it fits to my needs. 10x !

Comment: The data for a particular key/window does not get buffered forever - with the default accumulation mode (discarding fired panes), the data will be GC'd as soon as DetectAnomaliesFn is applied to this particular key/values pair.

Comment: Discussing on comments isn't such a great method, so I will send an update below.